# Error running introductory example of scala-xml

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-xml

I'm trying to run the simple example provided on the [README of `scala-xml`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml), but the code won't run:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .option("rowTag", "book")
    .load("books.xml")
```

(copy-pasted from the README; `books.xml` is indeed in the local directory)

This gives me error:

> Name: Compile Error
>
> Message: :1: error: illegal start of definition
>
> ```
> .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
>
> ^
> ```
>
> StackTrace:

I'm running this from a Jupyter notebook with Spark/Scala kernel.

I'm sure there's a simple mistake, but I'm brand new to Scala/Spark.

Version info:

- Spark: 2.0.1
- Scala: 2.11.8

Comment: Which scala version? Try all the calls on one line.

Comment: @Reactormonk `which scala` suggests the version is `scala-2.11.8`

Comment: @Reactormonk running from one line gives a different error: "Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.xml. "... i don't see anything else on the README suggesting I need to do something else to import from databricks?

Comment: have you added the library dependencies ??? com.databricks:spark-xml_2.11:0.4.1 ??

Answer (score 0):

you can add packages to the  Spark using the --packages command line option

As per the comment and question, you should try running the code in one line it will solve your  problem of  "error: illegal start of definition"

```
val df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag", "book").load("book.xml")
```

Next for "Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.xml. "

try adding the library dependency/package `"com.databricks:spark-xml_2.11:0.4.1 "`

```
spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-xml_2.11:0.4.1

val df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag", "book").load("book.xml")



df.show
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+-----+------------+--------------------+
|  _id|              author|         description|          genre|price|publish_date|               title|
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+-----+------------+--------------------+
|bk101|Gambardella, Matthew|An in-depth look ...|       Computer|44.95|  2000-10-01|XML Developer's G...|
|bk102|          Ralls, Kim|A former architec...|        Fantasy| 5.95|  2000-12-16|       Midnight Rain|
|bk103|         Corets, Eva|After the collaps...|        Fantasy| 5.95|  2000-11-17|     Maeve Ascendant|
```

Comment: How can I run this from a Jupyter notebook? i.e., how can I add command-line options to a Scala kernel in Jupyter?